# setup.py: No module named *

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setup.py, python-packaging

I'm trying to develop a new Python module. This is the how my directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── cmd_dispatcher.py
├── commands
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── validate.py
├── hello.py
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── utils
    └── __init__.py
```

This is `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='abc',
    version='1.0',
    install_requires=[
        'Click',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        tdrivecli=cmd_dispatcher:mycli
    ''',
)
```

The `cmd_dispatcher.py` has code which does `from commands.validate import validate_something`

When I install this package using `pip install --editable .`
and run `$ mycli` I get

```
  File "cmd_dispatcher.py", line 3, in <module>
    from commands.validate import validate_cst
ImportError: No module named validate
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could try moving cmd_dispatcher.py and commands/ into src/ with an __init__.py so as to make your code a single package

Answer (score 0):

`commands` is a module in Python 2.7 (https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) so your package may clash with it. Make sure you don't have absolute import enabled in your cmd_dispatcher and it really can find your package.